# Updating Fragments from an IntentService

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intentservice

The application that I'm working on has an activity with three fragments. Each fragment needs to show some data that is received from an IntentService.

Fragment 1 - the icon, the name and the description
Fragment 2 - a list of articles
Fragment 3 - a list of items

```
public class Activity extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements Actionbar.Tablistener
{

    public void onCreate(..) {

        ....
        performSearch();
        setupTabs(); // 3 tabs are setup, their clicks and swipes init'ed
        ...

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() { 

      IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(SearchRequestReceiver.ACTION);
      intentFilter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
      searchRequestReceiver = new SearchRequestReceiver(this);
      registerReceiver(searchRequestReceiver, intentFilter);

    }

    @Override 
    public void onPause() {

      unregisterReceivers();

    }
    ...

    public void performSearch() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SearchRequest.class);
        intent.putExtra("searchTerm", this.searchTerm); // declared and initialised earlier
        startService(intent);
    }

    ...
}
```

What is the best way for me to push this data from my receiver to my fragments or am I approaching this the wrong way? I didn't use AsyncTasks because I wanted to decouple my services from the context or was that the wrong decision?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An EventBus is one of the neatest solutions in this situation. [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) and [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/) are both very easy to use.

An example using Otto...

#### Your IntentService

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
   bus.post(new DataLoadCompleteEvent());
});
```

Note the necessity to post the event on Android's main thread with Otto. In this case, a `DataLoadCompleteEvent` could contain whatever you wanted.

#### Your Fragment

```
@Subscribe public void onLoad(DataLoadCompleteEvent event) {
    //Do stuff with event
}
```

Just make sure your Fragments register on the bus in their `onResume()`, and unregister in their `onPause()`.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get it working by having the different receivers within my fragments but it seems like an awful lot of repetition.

```
public class FragmentName extends SherlockFragment 
{

   private SearchRequestReceiver searchRequestReceiver;

   ..

   public class ServiceRequestReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
   {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            ...

        }

   }

}
```

Is there a better way?